# Get data from column array in mysql from php

Tags: php, sql

I have a database like this:

```
id   |   data
1        a:3:{s:12:"question1";s:1:"a";s:7:"question2";s:1:"b";}
2        a:3:{s:12:"question1";s:1:"c";s:7:"question2";s:1:"d";}
```

And I need to get the values of "question1". Any idea how can i get it?

Thanks guys

Comment: What you mean by `values of "question1"`?

Comment: Query, loop, `unserialize()`, access array.

Comment: seems that your serialized strings aren't well created, trying to `unserialize` them return false

Comment: @HamletHakobyan the values of "question1" are "a" and "c" and value of "question2" "b" and "d".

Comment: Still doesn't explain how they came up with that string. ID 1 is supposed to be an array of three elements, but it actually has four. If ID 1 were valid, it'd look like this: `a:4:{i:0;s:9:"question1";i:1;s:1:"a";i:2;s:9:"question2";i:3;s:1:"b";}`

Comment: There are many other questions like this, OP simply did not look.

Comment: Basically is an array of question1 and question2 @mounty

Comment: What I'm saying is, if that's what it's supposed to be, then someone put it in the DB wrong. Because those strings as they exist in the database can't be unserialized. There's certainly a way to untangle that mess programmatically, but I'd start by going back to whoever put this in the db in the first place and finding out how they arrived at the values we see here. If they wrote some sort of custom serializer, they should have a custom unserializer, too.